# How to properly set python kernels in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

If I list the jupyter kernels I get the following

```
jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/myName/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
  python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
```

However if I open `jupyter` and I choose `python3` as kernel I get that it is running `python2`

[image]

How can I properly set the kernel to the specific python version? I am working on mac machine and I have installed everything trough `pip3`

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter isn't running Python2, the shell is (via the `!` cell magic)

If you want the actual version of the interpreter, then

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

You can also see in the top-right that it clearly says *Python 3*, and unclear why you doubt that to be true